# evaluating the integral $\int_{\frac{k\pi}{n}}^{\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n}}{|\sin(nx)|dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I have to prove that :

$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty } \int_{0}^{\pi}{f(x)|\sin(nx)=\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\pi}{f(x)dx}$

I found in the notes that we can rewrite

$\int_{0}^{\pi}{f(x)|\sin(nx)|dx}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{f(x_{k})\int_{\frac{k\pi}{n}}^{\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n}}{|\sin(nx)|dx}}$

but I'm stuck with this integral

$\int_{\frac{k\pi}{n}}^{\frac{(k+1)\pi}{n}}{|\sin(nx)|dx}$

Thanks in advamce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $nx=t$, by periodicity one get $I=2/n$. Now use the definition of R integral.